# Библеотека Docx падает при попытки вставить в docx текст. C#

Tags: c#, .net, docx

Всем привет. Я тут столкнулся с странностями библиотеки Docx и теперь не знаю что мне делать.
Код :

```
DocX document = DocX.Load("File1.docx");
Paragraph Plain = document.InsertParagraph();

Plain.InsertText( 220,Convert.ToString("ЧТО ТО ТУТ!")+"ч.;");
```

И она падает на третей строке этого кода :

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Заданный аргумент находится вне диапазона допустимых значений." Но мне нужно написать на этом месте текста...

Прошу помогите.

Comment: `Convert.ToString("string".ToString())`

Comment: Стеб понятен, но там вместо "Что то тут" должно стоять число).  Не в этом проблемма)

Comment: А Вы уверены, что в тексте есть 220 символов? Я правильно понимаю, что 220 - это индекс символа в строке?

Comment: Даже на 1 падает(

Comment: Всем тем кто , хочет убрать c# из заголовка. Оставьте его в покое, он для того, чтобы по названию понять что за язык

Comment: @Shadow: тэга достаточно) Тэг языка отображается сразу под заголовком + люди добавляют интересные им тэги в отслеживающиеся, так что вопросы по ним будут подсвечиваться. Так что шарписты все равно не прошли бы мимо Вашего вопроса)

Comment: Увы но нет) Тут есть "Похожие", что правее основного косяка спора - В них не показываются тэги)

Answer (score 0):

Так как параграф пустой передавайте index 0.

```
Plain.InsertText(0,Convert.ToString("ЧТО ТО ТУТ!")+"ч.;");
```

Ссылка на проверку [DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX/blob/85af727e20e5b1d8cba8127bfa985a6d214c113c/Xceed.Words.NET/Src/Paragraph.cs#L4419)

Comment: Предложенное вами решение работает , также как и без индекса - вставляет в конце текста. А мне нужно было в середине...

Comment: http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2009/08/docx-version-1006-released.html - вообще Я опирался на это, но у автора инструкций, как всегда все чудесно робит, а у меня не фига)

Comment: если текст должен быть в середине используйте свойство `Alignment` : `Plain.Alignment = Alignment.center;`. Если нужно изменить уже существующий параграф, то тогда все как в статье.

Comment: В центре не страницы, а текста)  Пример:   "БЛАБЛАБЛАБЛА!" В мне надо вставить  "БЛАБЛА!БЛАБЛА!" .  в том то и дело, что у автора статьи робит. У меня неа